# Is Superman's Kryptonite vulnerability common knowledge in the DC Universe?

Tags: dc, superman

Lex Luther and Batman (among others) both know and use Kryptonite against Superman. But what about the man on the street? Has the Wikipedia of the DC verse figured it out yet, or has it somehow been kept a secret?

This question pertains to the main canon Comic books (New 52) and Movie canon.

Comment: I reckon it changes from canon to canon, are you referring to one in particular? I know in one, he gave a press conference and told the world he was weak to Kryptonite, I think he wanted to sound as transparent as he could to everyone he was trying to protect.

Comment: I suppose I'm interested in the current 'main' canon. So, movies and the new 52?

Comment: Maybe pop that into your question? Could help someone track down an answer for you.

Comment: You “suppose” you’re interested in the current main canon? You need to pick your canon son! This isn’t make-believe fun-tim story-hour, this is comics! *GO BIG OR GO HOME!*

Comment: Paul is right Fhnuzoag, people are **VERY** particular about canons around these parts...

Comment: Kryptonite has been used against Superman publicly on countless occasions. Even if the common person doesn't know what that green rock is, it seems unlikely that they wouldn't have picked up on its significance to Superman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The government recently detonated a Kryptonite bomb (Action Comics 32) in the atmosphere so I'm pretty sure a few people are going to figure it out.

[image: Kryptonite bomb in the atmosphere]

In the news clip intro to Action Comics' 33 there's mention of it in what I assume to be a publicly available publication although it could be simply the author's "Last week on Superman".

[image: Periodical about Kryptonite]

Seems likely that

Comment: I know I'm *extremely* late here, but your answer appears to have been cut off partway through. "Seems likely that"... what?